# error: undefined reference to `QVTKWidget::QVTKWidget(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'

Tags: qt, vtk, point-cloud-library, qvtkwidget

I m using Qt5.15 in Ubuntu 20.04. I want to use PCL to visualise point cloud data. To get PCL runnig with Qt, VTK library is also required. So in my system I have PCL 1.10 and VTK 7.1.1. I have taken sample code for testing the setup from [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer). I m getting following error:

```
error: undefined reference to `QVTKWidget::QVTKWidget(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'
```

Any suggestion for resolving this?

Comment: This project is using cmake build system so there is no .pro file, it is using the CMakeLists.txt only. I see in the Qt creator it is able to recognise the vtk directory.

Comment: I take my comments back the CMakeLists.txt does not properly link to vtk

Comment: This example should help: [https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/RenderWindowNoUiFile](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/RenderWindowNoUiFile)

Comment: I tried it as well, this program is throwing another error: **'fatal error: QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget.h: No such file or directory.'** This file is not there neither in my VTK build folder or in /usr/local/include/vtk-8.1

Comment: I think you need to install this package and its dependencies: [https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libvtk7-qt-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libvtk7-qt-dev)

Comment: @drescherjm These packages were automatically installed when I installed PCL.

Comment: I think the problem is, I m copying the libQVTKWidgetPlugin.so in /plugins/designer/ directory of Qt but the qt creator is not able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Install Qt, Build VTK with QT_DIR set and Install. Build PCL with VTK_DIR and visualization module set. Install PCL. If custom install dirs add them to ubuntu’s ldconfig. I prefer building with cmake in qtcreator. Create new project in qtcreator and choose cmake as compiler in wizzard